# Showing invalid syntax

Tags: sql, select

[image: its a database column companies under the database company_directory]

```
SELECT a.company_name FROM 
         (SELECT companies.company_name 
        FROM companies WHERE  companies.profile_progress 
        BETWEEN 80 AND 100) a ORDER BY  RAND() DESC LIMIT 9 u ORDER BY profile_progress
```

facing issue with this error
Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'u ORDER BY profile_progress' at line 4 in C:\xampp\htdocs\company-directory\home.php:20 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\company-directory\home.php(20): PDOStatement->execute() #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\company-directory\home.php on line 20

Comment: You have two `ORDER BY` clauses, so your query is not syntactically correct.

Answer (score 1):

No need to use sub query, you can directly use `ORDER BY` clause and also not sure what is the purpose you use `RAND()` function in the `ORDER BY` clause, it is a function that generates random numbers and there is no point in sorting using the function. You can sort with respective column and fetch the result.

```
SELECT companies.company_name 
FROM companies WHERE  companies.profile_progress 
BETWEEN 80 AND 100 ORDER BY profile_progress LIMIT 9;
```

Comment: I do want to show 9 rows of data on each refresh of the page if the profile_progress database values are the same, that's why I have used rand ()

Comment: You can just use `LIMIT` 9, no need to use `RAND()` function